# CSS to take into account buttons across the top?

Tags: css

I have an iFrame that loads flash content. I want this content to take up whatever portion of the screen is left. So the frame has a height of 100%, but I noticed the bottom gets cut off a little bit, causing the some of the flash content to be cut off. How can I write some CSS to sort of calculate what 100% of the rest of the page is (I have some bootstrap buttons at the top of this interface that take up some space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CSS3, you can use the calc function like this:

```
height: calc(100% - 30px);
```

Or whatever the height of you button bar.

Comment: I really like the `calc()` function, unfortunately looks like it does not work in many browsers (not been implemented yet), sadly.

Comment: Also note that the spaces between operands are needed (at least in this case), such as writing `100%-30px` won't work, interestingly, maybe that's why I thought `calc()` was not supported, but it's really mordern indeed (old versions may not understand).

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning your flash box as `absolute`, don't set its width and height explicitly in CSS and just set the offset `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` like this:

```
div {        
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  top:30px;
  left:100px;
  right:100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZSLH/4/)